# Is there any way to know the last commit value in a table?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.5.  If I update certain values of a row and commit, is there any way to fetch the old value afterwards?  I am thinking is there something like a flashback?  But this would be a selective flashback.  I don't want to rollback the entire database.  I just need to revert one row.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but if your business logic requires knowing the immediate previous value, you could always add a column for this.

Comment: Yes that's the last resort in my plan. Just wanted to know if there is any way to rollback to the last value.

Comment: You can create an audit table that stores the changes. See [here](http://okbob.blogspot.de/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) [here](http://cjauvin.blogspot.de/2013/05/impossibly-lean-audit-system-for.html) or [here](https://eager.io/blog/audit-postgres/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - it is not possible.

But for future readers, you can create an array field with historical data that will look something like this:

```
     Column     |           Type           | 
----------------+--------------------------+------
 value          | integer                  | 
 value_history  | integer[]                |
```

For more info read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) about arrays